# Using computed fields in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to use a runtime-computed field in my admin page. This works fine, but I'd like to allow sorting based for that field. Using Django 1.5 (dev), is this possible? I've been scouring the interweb but can't find anything indicating that it *is* possible.

```
class Guest(models.Model)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Invitation(models.Model)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["email", "latest_invitation_sent_on",]

    def latest_invitation_sent_on(self, o):
        try:
            return o.invitation_set.all().order_by(
                "-created_on")[0].created_on.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        except IndexError:
            return "N/A"
```

I'd like to be able to enable sorting by `latest_invitation_sent_on`. Are there any methods of doing this nicely that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to annotate Guests with their latest invitation time and then order_by it (order_by uses the DB to sort and as long as you can provide a valid DB field, table or virtual it should work).

```
class GuestManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(GuestManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(latest_invite=Max("invitation_set__created_on"))

class Guest(models.Model)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = GuestManager()    

class Invitation(models.Model)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["email", "latest_invite",]
```

If you only need `latest_invite` annotation once in a while it makes sense to move it to a separate method or even manager.

```
class GuestManager(models.Manager):
    def by_invitations(self):
        return super(GuestManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(latest_invite=Max("invitation_set__created_on")).order_by('-latest_invite')

>>>  Guest.objects.by_invitations()
```

Comment: Using your first chunk of code, I get `GuestAdmin.list_display[4], 'latest_invite' is not a callable or an attribute of 'GuestAdmin' or found in the model 'Guest'.`. This is odd because if I stick in a `print o.latest_invite` in the `queryset` method of the admin class, it prints fine. For some reason, `list_display` is failing on it though..

Comment: @DemianBrecht Instead of using a manager just add another instance method to the class that returns its `created_on`

Comment: A note to future readers: since Django 1.6, the `get_query_set` method has been renamed to `get_queryset`